# DataTable row to display in modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Having put together a datatable, and modal for row on click.
However, I am having trouble with getting the datatable content to render inside the modal. With information from each column of the row displaying under a unique span class.

This is my html. Where the table head is defined below, and table body rendered from the JS:

```
<!-- Datatable here -->
<table id="grabbed-report" class="display" width="100%">
     <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Alpha:</th>
            <th>Bravo:</th>
            <th>Charlie:</th>
            <th>Delta:</th>
            <th>Echo:</th>
            <th>Foxtrot:</th>
            <th>Golf:</th>
            <th>Hotel:</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>


<!-- Modal here -->
<div class="modal fade" id="globesModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content here-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Details</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="alpha"><p>Alpha: </p><span></span></div>
      <div class="bravo"><p>Bravo: </p><span></span></div>
      <div class="charlie"><p>Charlie: </p><span></span></div>
      <div class="delta"><p>Delta: </p><span></span></div> 
      <div class="echo"><p>Echo: </p><span></span></div>
      <div class="foxtrot"><p>Foxtrot: </p><span></span></div>
      <div class="golf"><p>Golf: </p><span></span></div>
       <div class="hotel"><p>Hotel: </p><span></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Working from the datatable documentation, I think I have put together my JS correctly:

```
 $('#grabbed-report').DataTable({
        searching: true,
        responsive: true,
        // Data from JS
        data: grabbingData,
        columns: [
            { data: "Alpha" },
            { data: "Bravo" },
            { data: "Charlie" },
            { data: "Delta" },
            { data: "Echo" },
            { data: "Foxtrot" },
            { data: "Golf" },
            { data: "Hotel" }
        ],
        "autoWidth": false,
    });
```

So I believe that the issue may be with my JQuery targeting the row content?

To try and troubleshoot, I have added a console log to make sure that the information is captured on row click. Confirming that it is. However, it doesn't appear to come through under the respective span elements. So I may not be targeting these correctly? I have tried both .text and also .html

Here is the JQuery for the modal:

```
//Modal setup:
    $('#grabbed-report tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
       console.log(table.row(this).data());
        $(".modal-body div span").text("");
        $(".alpha span").text(table.row(this).data()[1]);
        $(".bravo span").text(table.row(this).data()[1]);
        $(".charlie span").text(table.row(this).data()[2]);
        $(".delta span").text(table.row(this).data()[3]).hide();
        $(".echo span").text(table.row(this).data()[4]);
        $(".foxtrot span").text(table.row(this).data()[5]);
        $(".golf span").text(table.row(this).data()[6]);
        $(".hotel span").text(table.row(this).data()[7]);
        $("#globesModal").modal("show");
    });
```

Copy of my sample data:

```
var grabbingData = [
{
"Alpha":"Test",
"Bravo":"Tester",
"Charlie":"Test Test",
"Delta":"Tester 2",
"Echo":"Tester3",
"Foxtrot":"Tester 4",
"Golf":"Tester 5",
"Hotel":"Tester 6"
}
];
```

I have put together a JSFiddle of what I am trying to get to work. The weird thing is, if I change the datatable from being compiled from JS, and just embed as a static html table on the page, the modal starts to works correctly.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pixelmedia/oxem1z85/30/

A fresh perspective would be really appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is quite an old post but has over 1k views so...

To get a working version of this code, modify the JQuery to reference the fields directly. So

```
$(".alpha span").text(table.row(this).data()[0]);
```

becomes

```
 $(".alpha span").text(table.row(this).data().Alpha);
```

```js
    //Modal setup:
    $('#grabbed-report tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
       console.log(table.row(this).data());
       
        $(".modal-body div span").text("");
        $(".alpha span").text(table.row(this).data().Alpha);
        $(".bravo span").text(table.row(this).data().Bravo);
        $(".charlie span").text(table.row(this).data().Charlie);
        $(".delta span").text(table.row(this).data().Delta).hide();
        $(".echo span").text(table.row(this).data().Echo);
        $(".foxtrot span").text(table.row(this).data().Foxtrot);
        $(".golf span").text(table.row(this).data().Golf);
        $(".hotel span").text(table.row(this).data().Hotel);
        $("#globesModal").modal("show");
    });
} );
```